# Remove Bottom shadow effect in Bottom Navigation Bar flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

[image]

Bottom Navigation bar in iPhone 11 has bottom shadow as seen in the above picture, is there any way to remove the shadow?

```
floatingActionButtonLocation: FloatingActionButtonLocation.centerDocked,
    bottomNavigationBar: BottomAppBar(
      clipBehavior: Clip.antiAliasWithSaveLayer,
      shape: CircularNotchedRectangle(),
      child: Theme(
        data: Theme.of(buildContext)
            .copyWith(canvasColor: Colors.white, primaryColor: Colors.grey),
        child: BottomNavigationBar(
          onTap: (index){
            
          },
          type: BottomNavigationBarType.fixed,
          items: bottomNavigationBar.map((element) {
            return BottomNavigationBarItem(
                icon: Icon(element["icon"]), title: Text(element["title"]));
          }).toList(),
        ),
      ),
    ));
```

[image]

Edit : This is result that I get after setting elevation : 0

[image]

Edit : After adding the safearea bottomAppBar shadow problem solved but is it possible to retain the statusBarColor (notch area) which I had previously ?

Comment: Please try elevation : 0 of BottomAppBar

Comment: elevation: 0, removes the shadow at top of the bottom navigation bar. the bottom shadow remains unchanged :(

Comment: I have gone through the above code and elevation=0 works perfectly as you want. Can you share the image of how you are getting bottomAppBar after adding elevation=0 if possible?

Comment: I have added the resultant image after setting elevation : 0 in BottomAppBar

Comment: What if you wrap the whole `Scaffold` with `SafeArea` ? I guess the problem is with the curved edges of the screen. `elevation` is only for the top of the navbar, not the bottom.

Comment: Thanks, Safe Area solved the bottom app bar problem, is it possible to retain the statusBarColor (notch area) which I had previously?

Answer (score 7):

Inside your BottomNavigationBar put `elevation: 0.0`
Example:

```
child: BottomNavigationBar(
        type: BottomNavigationBarType.fixed,
        backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
        elevation: 0.0,
```

[BottomNavigationBar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T2QG4.png)